# Get thinner thighs

Tags: diet, thigh

I want to lose weight from my thighs and legs, but i have no time at all for exercising.

How can I achieve that using nutrition only? is it possible? 
I read this [article](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/anne-dunev/three-weeks-to-thinner-th_b_181045.html), is this diet efficient, or a little bit over?

I don't want to use chemicals, medicines, or creams.

Comment: In Matt's answer, you'll notice the phrase "you can't **Target** areas ...". You'll see this theme over and again if you search the fitness.SE site. Just lose weight and hope it comes off in the right areas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a pretty good "standard" healthy diet. There's no real way to "target" areas for JUST fat loss.  Exercising will definitely do it the fastest, but that diet will cut fat off your whole body, and therefore your thighs as well.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, spot reductions are generally not possible. Healthy diet and an exercise regimen can help in an overall weight and fat loss and toned body. You can try elliptical, running, lunges and squats for toning of legs. There are certain Yoga poses and exercises you could try too. There is one Yogasana where you flutter your legs like a butterfly in a sitting pose ( I am not sure of the name of the Asana) but it helps tone the inner thighs.